# explanation of variable setting formula in Java required

Tags: java

i have this java code:

weight = weight == 0 ? 1 : weight;

Can anyone please explain what will happen to variable weight in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

If weight equals 0, then weight will be set to 1, else it remains unchanged.

Many people don't like the ternary ? operator, because it is harder to read. Those people would write

```
if (weight == 0) {
    weight = 1;
}
```

And they have a point there, I'd say.